# Sound Output Meaning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So I added a sound (.wav) in my `UIButton` when pressed, but It outputs this in the Debugger, can anyone explain or help me on what this is :

```
2012-06-21 10:29:51.784 PhotoSlot[817:1dc0b] The default input device's sample rate was changed.
2012-06-21 10:29:51.786 PhotoSlot[817:21a2b] Audio device's sample rate changed. You may need to restart the simulator.
2012-06-21 10:29:51.786 PhotoSlot[817:1dd0f] Default audio device changed. Restart the simulator to have it use the newly-selected device.
```

Here is my code for the sound:

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/push.wav"];
    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:NULL];
//set our delegate and begin playback
player.delegate = self;
[player play];
```

Thankyou.

> 2012-06-21 11:24:09.702 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-06-21 11:24:09.711 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-06-21 11:24:09.996 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-06-21 11:24:10.006 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-06-21 11:24:10.024 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-06-21 11:24:10.033 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-06-21 11:24:10.053 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-06-21 11:24:10.071 PhotoSlot[1578:1a303] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation

Comment: It *might* be useful to see if the "`error`" parameter in your "`AVAudioPlayer`" instantiation returns anything other than NULL.  Also, do you set player to nil (if using ARC) or release it (if not using ARC) when you're done with it?

Comment: no i haven't set my player to nil, could it be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh, posting the error helps me out.  [I found this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean) which also has the same output as what you're seeing.

But I think the real solution you should be doing (assuming you're using ARC), [is found in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744831/981049):  you need to keep a strong reference for your "`AVAudioPlayer`" instance around while the sound is playing.  Make your player a "`strong`" ivar (instance variable) and before playing a new sound, set "`self.player = nil;`" and that should fix your problem.

Also, turn off all breakpoints in your simulator debugger and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Thankyou, it was fine, But its kinda loads slow after I pressed my button.

Comment: "it was fine" = you solved your problem?  If it loads kind of slow after you press your button, do you have a massive sound file or something?

Comment: my .wav is only 8Kb, but Im applying a core animation in my button, Is it because of the animation, because my animation is continuous blinking,

Comment: might be!  I'm glad your sound issues seem to be solved, though.

Comment: Still displaying the error, but I have read the links you posted, said it was safe. Thanks.