# Objective-C - AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I found that using AVAudioFoundation should be the easiest way to play an mp3 on objective-c, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. No sound on either the device or the simulator. I imported the framework and all the other "normal" things, but it just keep not playing. What is wrong in this code?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DuomoDiFirenze" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[theAudio prepareToPlay];
[theAudio play];
```

Comment: not sure which player I am using at home, but some functions doesn't work on simulator for sure, eg volume up. I highly recommend to skip simulators while doing Audio / Video stuff

Comment: As I wrote, I tried it also on the device, but it's the same. No sound at all. I think the problem is not the simulator.

Comment: if I would know what is the error, than I would set an error and give it to `initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:` and I would log it after that

Comment: Maybe same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692866/avaudioplayer-stops-playing-immediately-with-arc/7744831#7744831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you compile with ARC? if so make sure to keep a reference to the `AVAudioPlayer` instance as else ARC will make sure to release it for you and the audio playback will stop immediately.

Comment: Yeah, I do use ARC. But what do you mean with "keep a reference to the AVAudioPlayer instance"?

NVM. I'm reading your comment on the other answer.

Comment: To assign it to a property or a instance variable for example.

Comment: This solved it for me. The "free" variable (I don't know how it is called actually, when a var is not attached to any object, but in a loop or something, declared on the fly) didn't work, but as a property, AVAudioPlayer worked as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

So when you declare `AVAudioPlayer * theAudio` as a property of whichever object you are using it it, it will work. That's the only thing you are missing.