# play sound while app in call and speaker is occupied by call

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app is a calling app and I want to play a mp3 file during the call (call in my app not the iphone voice call). AvAudioPlayer play return YES so it means sound is played but I do not hear the sound played.

the mp3 file I want to play is a simple small beep sound which I want to play to inform the caller during the call.

Any idea why I can not hear the sound or is there a way for this.
thanks a lot.

Comment: @NitinGohel ***What???*** Disabling ARC makes sound work magically? I don't even...

Comment: @H2CO3 few day ago i working play sound Demo using AvAudioPlayer i create new project with enable ARC i put code req for playing sound but it not play i do search and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692866/avaudioplayer-stops-playing-immediately-with-arc so i suggest him to disable ARC

Comment: @NitinGohel Then you are doing something seriously wrong (I mean, in your code).

Comment: but after i disable ARC then run project that working fine. :)

Comment: it plays well when I am not in call .. so I doubt on the speaker occupied by the call.

Comment: Ohh ok sorry for my misunderstanding.. i assume that you face you not here sound so i thought might be this prob from ARC

Comment: @NitinGohel If disabling ARC fixed your project, then you either don't understand the retain-release model or something important was being set to nil.  Either way, you now have a functioning project that is a giant ball of memory leaks.  Have fun!

Comment: Check the mode of the audio player.  You probably want the sound to mix with that of the audio context of the call.

Comment: thanks @CodaFi I tried setting the mode as below. now I hear the beep sound but its not playing on speaker, my call is running  on speaker so I want it to be played in the same mode.                      [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:nil];