# AVAudioPlayer Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer

On playing more than 1 songs using AVAudio Player

when the first song get finished  `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` get called .

if i use that code it works

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSString *tempString = @"/";
    tempString  = [tempString stringByAppendingString:name];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    path = [path stringByAppendingString:tempString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSError *error;

    AVAudioPlayer  *audioPlayer101 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url    error:&error];

    [AppDelegate getAppdelegate].audioPlayerForPlay = audioPlayer101;
    [[AppDelegate getAppdelegate].audioPlayerForPlay play];
}
```

It works

however if i does not put the instance in perdefined property of audio player it doesnot play.

here is that code

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSString *tempString = @"/";
    tempString  = [tempString stringByAppendingString:name];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    path = [path stringByAppendingString:tempString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSError *error;

    AVAudioPlayer  *audioPlayer101 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url    error:&error];
    [audioPlayer101  play];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692866/avaudioplayer-stops-playing-immediately-with-arc

Comment: Long story  (see link in comment above) short, ARC releases you `audioPlayer101` right after you create it; the easiest way to fix is to make storng ivar, like in your first chunk of code (where you have ivar in AppDelegate)

Comment: In my scenario i have multiple audio players playing at the same time and i need the instance of  each audio player separately. is there any solution to implement the second test case perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the ARC code

```
AVAudioPlayer  *audioPlayer101 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url    error:&error];
[audioPlayer101  play];
```

will be compile to for Non-ARC

```
AVAudioPlayer  *audioPlayer101 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url    error:&error];
[audioPlayer101  play];
[audioPlayer101 release];
```

And the `audioPlayer101` will be released as soon as it create, because system will not retain it automatically and release lead to dealloc make play stop.

If you use `instance.audioPlayerForPlay = audioPlayer101;` like your code, and the property of  `audioPlayerForPlay` is `strong`, the play will be retained by instance, so can the play can keep playing. You can try set `audioPlayerForPlay to be`weak`, the previous code will not play as well.